# How to hide and show apply radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>

<script>
$('input:radio[name=sex]')[1].checked = true;
</script>
```

This is all of the code I have to use. I can't manipulate the input radio buttons because those are being served up by a third party system. What I need to know is how can I write the jQuery to show the 'Female' radio button but hide the 'Male' and 'Unknown' radio buttons as the page loads.

Comment: Will the `value` always be the same

Comment: Do you want to hide just the radio buttons, or the text next to them as well? Also, if you're looking to hide things, why does your jQuery code refer to `checked`?

Comment: Input tags shouldn't be opened and closed like that. I know you can't control the HTML, but someone should know they're doing it wrong.

Comment: And on topic, to check values on change event for radio buttons you should get the jquery object of the radio names eg sex. Only then you can check if value === "female" do stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$(function() {
  $('input:radio[name=sex]:not([value=Female])').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either one of these...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input:radio[value=Male]').hide();
        $('input:radio[value=Unknown]').hide();
    });
</script>
```

They're both the same - it just depends on what you prefer to look at

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('input:radio[value=Male], input:radio[value=Unknown]').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your examples did remove the radio button which is pretty cool. Is there a way to target the innerHTML part too?

Comment: I would also like to hide the words 'Male' and 'Unknown'

Comment: Not the way you've currently got it, as you can't put text inside `input` elements.  It actually renders that text after the element in the browser.  You'd need to enclose the text in an element in order to hide it.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I was able to add a class which enabled me to hide the text of the input element. You guys helped a lot because now I have the ability to hide the radio buttons I choose and the text associated with it. Forcing a third party system to do what you want without having complete source code access is awful but I got what I needed. Whew!